# React Static Website Problem Deploying on GCP (can't find main.js or main.css)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, progressive-web-apps

I followed this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website to host my React webapp. Here is what I have so far:

```
// app.yaml
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static

  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$
    
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

(I've tried MANY configurations here)

I run `npm run build` and put the build directory in GCP Cloud Storage along with `app.yaml`. When I go to my website I get this:

[image]

This happens when I hit the root url.

It looks like it is looking at the `static` directory which should then look at `build/static` according to my `app.yaml`.

[image]

If I go directly to the webpage such as `https://www.drinkingbuddy.io/build/static/js/main.39aaab31.js`, the browser displays the file as expected. So it is there being hosted but something is messed up with pathing? I'm not sure.

Testing locally, everything works. Even when serving the build files.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Another thing is that when I go to the base url, it just shows the document tree.[image]

**EDIT 2:**
When accessing the files directly from the bucket such as https://www.storage.googleapis.com/drinkingbuddy-static/build/index.html, I then get this error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>UserProjectAccountProblem</Code>
<Message>User project billing account not in good standing.</Message>
<Details>The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent</Details>
</Error>
```

But looking through my account I don't see any billing issues.

**EDIT 3:**

Now I am able to get to `.../build/index.html` and it displays my site. but the root `/` is still throwing errors saying it can't find main.js. I added `homepage: "."` to my package.json.

Comment: All js files, CSS files that are accessed in `index.html` should have a relative path. To do so, in your `package.json`, specify `homepage: "/drinkingbuddy-static"`. Then when you run the command `npm run build` it will add the relative path `drinkingbuddy-static` in the `index.html`. Now try to access `https://www.storage.googleapis.com/drinkingbuddy-static/index.html` and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I was actually able to get it to work now by doing `homepage: "/build"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by doing `homepage:"/build"`. Now I can access the root url and get expected behavior.